# WebView canZoomIn and canZoomOut not working on OS 2.3?

Tags: android

It is working on OS 2.1 and 2.2, but not on OS 2.3.

Comment: what is working dear? please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

The `canZoomIn()` and `canZoomOut()` methods from the WebView class need at least API Level 11 (OS 3.0). See [WebView.html#canZoomIn](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canZoomIn%28%29) and [WebView.html#canZoomOut](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canZoomOut%28%29)